# How to pipe git log to curl command

Tags: bash, scripting, pipe, curl

My goal is to perform a `curl` with the output of a command as `curl` payload, separately they work, but I have not been able to merge both things into one.

This is my first command, it prints the changes in a GIT repo after the last version

```
git log --pretty=oneline HEAD...$(git tag -l | tail -n2 | head -n1)
```

Ok now I would want to introduce this output somehow into this curl sentence

```
curl -vX POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"text": "< GIT LOG OUTPUT >"}' https://example.com
```

Is there any way to pipe in a single line this 2 commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
curl -vX POST --data-urlencode \
    "payload={\"text\":\"`git log --pretty=oneline HEAD...$(git tag -l | tail -n2 | head -n1) | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's|,$||'`\"}" \
    https://<your-remote>
```

Comment: The issue is that after URL _decoding_ the JSON document in the payload, it will be an invalid JSON document since the value for the key `text` contains literal newlines (and possibly other characters that should have been JSON encoded when the document was created from the `git log` output).

Answer (score 0):

Using `jo` to create properly encoded JSON:

```
curl -vX POST --data-urlencode \
  payload="$(
    jo text="$(
      git log --pretty=oneline HEAD...$(git tag -l | tail -n2 | head -n1)
    )"
  )"
```

The main thing here is the command

```
jo text="$( git log ... )"
```

which will output a JSON document with a `text` key.  The value for that key will be the data outputted by `git log`, with newlines replaced by `\n` and whatever other characters replaced by the properly JSON encoded equivalent.

`jo` is readily available through your package manager on most Unices.